# Finding a Cartesian coordinate transformation matrix

Tags: linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, transformational-geometry

I have a vector, $u := [u_1, \ldots, u_n]^\mathrm{T}$. I am trying to find a coordinate transformation matrix, $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, which is nonsingular, satisfying:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ ||u|| \end{bmatrix} = Q u.
\end{align*}
I would appreciate any idea to find this matrix, $Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that if $W$ is a subespace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then
$$\dim(W)+\dim(W^{\perp})=n$$
Take $W$ as the span of $u$, so
$$\dim(<u>)=n-1.$$
You can construct a matrix $Q$ that will satisfy the same condition taking any set of $n-1$ vectors $v_i$ **from any basis of the ortogonal complement of the span of $u$**.
$$Q=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
v_{11}&v_{12}&\cdots&v_{1n}\\
v_{21}&v_{22}&\cdots &v_{2n}\\
v_{31}&v_{32}&\cdots&v_{3n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
v_{n-1,1}&v_{n-1,2}&\cdots&v_{n-1,n}\\
\displaystyle{\frac{u_1}{\vert\vert{u}\vert\vert}}&\displaystyle{\frac{u_2}{\vert\vert{u}\vert\vert}}&\cdots&\displaystyle{\frac{u_n}{\vert\vert{u}\vert\vert}}\\
\end{array}\right)$$
where $v_{i}=(v_{i1},\ldots,v_{in})^{T}$ are vectors in a basis $\{v_{1},\ldots,v_{n-1}\}$ of the **ortogonal complement** of the linear span of $u$, for all $i$ with $1\leq i\leq n-1$.

> **Remark:** This matrix **$Q$ is non singular** because it's rows are linearly independent because the following set is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$:
>   $$\mathcal{B}=\{u,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\}$$
>
> Also: You can use **Gram Schmidt process** to get an ortogonal basis of $<u>^{\perp}$ starting from $u$. In this way you will find the rights vectors $v_i$ such that $Q$ is inversible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I omitted an info that Q should be nonsingular.

Comment: Oh ! Yes sure, you want a matrix to do change of basis :)

Comment: You said it when you refer to coordinate transformation matrix, this matrix should be inversible. So, is my mistake :)

Comment: @H.C.: You can use my matrix $Q_1$ and Gram Schmidt algorithm see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: @H.C.: Look to this answer also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766613/proof-sum-of-dimension-of-orthogonal-complement-and-vector-subspace

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It perfectly makes sense and I could solve my problem.

Comment: No problem. Nice question :)