# Dimension of orthogonal complement

Tags: orthogonality, direct-sum

We know that if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ (finite-dimensional), then $V = U \oplus U^\perp$. Given this theorem, how does this lead to the conclusion that $\dim U^\perp = \dim V - \dim U$? This seems like a stupid question because it seems obvious, but I'm still unclear with this notion of a direct sum and the dimensions of subspaces adding up to the vector space.

Comment: $\dim V=\dim U + \dim U^\perp$

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766613/proof-sum-of-dimension-of-orthogonal-complement-and-vector-subspace)