# Correctness of this statement about vector subspces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was looking at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1766639/408807) and when it states:

> Given $v\in V$, then it is well-known that $v=v_1+v_2$ for some $v_1\in W$ and $v_2\in W^\perp$.

And then it proceed to state:

> $\beta\cup\gamma$ generates $V$.

I understand that $v=v_1+v_2$ will produce some of the elements in $V$ but that doesn't necessarily mean that it can produce *all* of the elements in $V$.

Is there a proof for this?

Comment: The statement you quote begins "Given $v\in V$,...". That language means that it applies to every $v\in V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. It follows from Hilbert's projection theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem).

Comment: Oh, I haven't learnt that yet. I will have a read about it then. Thanks!

Comment: In finite dimensions it's much easier. Choose a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$ of $V$, complete it to a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and perform Gram-Schmidt to get an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\{e_1,\ldots,e_r\}$ will span $V$ and the rest spans $V^\perp$, hence $\mathbb R^n = V\oplus V^\perp$.